# Apple Magic Trackpad resets settings after session

Tags: fedora, kde, input

I was able to get the Apple Magic Trackpad working on Fedora 15 KDE 4.6. (I previously got it working on Linux Mint.)

However, the settings -- particularly activating the single-finger left click and double-finger right click -- seem to reset after each user session.

Does anybody know how to retain these settings between sessions?

EDIT: When I turn on the computer and then activate the trackpad, then the settings do not load. However, when I logout and login, the settings load. That suggests to me that, since the trackpad is already active before login, its settings are successfully modified upon login. But when the trackpad is not active before login, then the default settings are meaningless because there is no trackpad to set.

Therefore, is there a way to register the settings *after* the trackpad is recognized by Bluetooth?

Answer (score 1):

Usually these settings would be set in the driver section of `xorg.conf`.

```
Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier     "Appletouch"
    Driver         "drivername"
    Option         "optionname" "value"
EndSection
```

For some systems there is also a client program that can set these values after X is running. For example synaptic touchpads have a configuration tool that you can change the various properties on the fly. I have actually taken to running that as part of my login script instead of setting it in X because it is easier to tweak.